# Why didn't China participate in the PISA 2022?

Tags: china, covid-19, education, oecd

> But that rosy spin hides a much grimmer picture. Rankings may have
> risen, but test scores did not. The only reason the U.S. rose is
> because academic performance in once higher ranking countries, such as
> Iceland and the Slovak Republic, fell by even more since the previous
> testing round in 2018. Neither India nor China, which topped the
> rankings in 2018, participated in the 2022 PISA. In math, the U.S.
> rose from 29th place to 28th place, still in the bottom half of
> economically advanced nations of the Organization for Economic
> Cooperation and Development (OECD), an international organization of
> 38 member countries that oversees the PISA exam.

https://hechingerreport.org/proof-points-there-is-a-worldwide-problem-in-math-and-its-not-just-about-the-pandemic/

China did participate in the PISA 2018 and topped the table, but for 2022 it didn't participate, except for Macau and Hong Kong, which are also part of China, so is there a reason why Shanghai didn't participate while Macau and Hong Kong both did? Did the Chinese government provide an official reason for not participating?

Comment: The answer by @user103496 provides a good response. Also, as a general observation, remember that many countries (to greater or lesser extent) were impacted by COVID19 with school closings in 2020, 2021, and in many cases, part or all of 2022.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*PISA 2022 Results: The State of Learning and Equity in Education Volume I*, p. 40 ([2023](https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/deliver/53f23881-en.pdf)):

> Chinese provinces/municipalities (Beijing, Shanghai, Jiangsu and Zhejiang) and Lebanon are participants in PISA 2022 but were unable to collect data because schools were closed during the intended data collection period.

(So, the quote is incorrect in claiming that China did not participate.)